# Unable to execute powershell command to create cluster in Windows Server 2016

Tags: java, powershell, cmd, cluster-computing, failover

Unable to execute the create cluster powershell command in java.

I have enabled enable-wsmancredssp in my server to prevent any privilege issue too. My server is Windows Server 2016.

```
  String command = "cmd /c start powershell \"New-Cluster -Name CLUSTER1 -node NODE1,NODE2 -StaticAddress 202.100.11.3 -AdministrativeAccessPoint Dns\"";

  Process clustering_process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); 
  clustering_process.waitFor();
```

No error message but i found some warning in tomcat log file.

```
04-Jul-2019 14:50:07.322 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/Portal]
04-Jul-2019 14:50:09.650 WARNING [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [Portal] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request processing thread:[
 java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
 java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
 java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
 sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
 sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
 java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
 java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
 java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 HA.HA.doPost(HA.java:400)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)]
```

Comment: Well I know how cluster work but never set one up, but from what I see it seems like it doesn't like it when the web application is running. Did you try to create the cluster with an running tomcat? Perhaps go to services and stop the tomcat for the process.
BR

Comment: Hi! I have tried executing the same command using command prompt in my server and it is able to create the cluster successfully. However, when executing the command in my java web application, it is unable to.

Comment: Well, i got some clues now as of why the cluster cannot be created. It is because of the privilege issue. Although I did enable-wsmancredssp in the nodes, there is no credentials to authenticate and allow the adding of nodes.

Comment: perhaps add a ps-session to the code where you can authenticate the session